# iOS, JSON check if value is false or string

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need to check if my value contains "false" or a string.

JSON:

```
{"success":true,"name":[{"image":false},{"image":"https:\/\/www.url.com\/image.png"}]}
```

My Code:

```
NSData *contentData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *content = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:contentData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

NSLog shows me for the first image value:

```
 NSLog(@"%@", content);
```

> image = 0;

I have a UICollectionView where I want to set an image from the URL.
If the value "image" is false, i want to put an other image, but i dont know how to check if it is false.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([[[content objectForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"] == nil)
```

I also tried "== false" "== 0" but nothing worked.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: "false" (when not enclosed in quotes) comes through as an NSNumber encoding a zero value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `false` comes in JSON, it gets deserialized as `NSNumber` with Boolean `false` inside it. You can do your comparison as follows:

```
// This is actually a constant. You can prepare it once in the static context,
// and use everywhere else after that:
NSNumber *booleanFalse = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
// This is the value of the "image" key from your JSON data
id imageObj = [[[content objectForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];
// Use isEqual: method for comparison, instead of the equality check operator ==
if ([booleanFalse isEqual:imageObj]) {
    ... // Do the replacement
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Split your code up to make it easier to read and debug. And it seems the value of "image" will either be a bool (as an `NSNumber`) or a url (as an `NSString`).

```
NSArray *nameData = content[@"name"];
NSDictionary *imageData = nameData[indexPath.row];
id imageVal = imageData[@"image"];
if ([imageVal isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSString *urlString = imageVal;
    // process URL
else if ([imageVal isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]) {
    NSNumber *boolNum = imageVal;
    BOOL boolVal = [boolNum boolValue];
    // act on YES/NO value as needed
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works also like the code from dasblinkenlight but i can only accept one answer.